# Get the list for Super and sub types

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am Having the Tables in SQL server as Super and Sub types like below. Now if i have to get list of Furnitures then how can i get the list?

Furniture table:

```
Id    FurnituretypeId NoofLegs
-------------------------------
1       1               4   
2       2               4
```

FurnitureType table:

```
Id     Name
-----------------
1    chair
2    cot
3    table
```

Chair Table:

```
Id    Name        CansSwing   CanDetachable      FurnitureId    
------------------------------------------------------------
1     Chair1         Y             Y                 1
```

Cot Table:

```
Id    Name        CotType      Storage   StorageType   FurnitureId
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Cot1       Auto           Y            Drawer       2
```

How can i get the entire furniture list as some of them are chair and some of them are cot. How can i join the these tables with furniture table and get the list?

Comment: What columns do you want from cot and chair? Do the names have to appear in one column only? Are there other common columns if the tables and if yes, should they appear only once? Or do you just want a list of the names and possibly the `FurnitureID`?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you need. Some sample data with expected result would solve that. Will there be cots and chairs whose furniture ID is not in the furniture table? Will there be furniture ID's which are not cots or chairs? What columns do you need to see in the final result?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . `union all` and `join`?

```
select cc.*, f.*
from ((select Id, Name, CansSwing, CanDetachable,
              NULL as CotType, NULL as Storage, NULL as StorageType, FurnitureId 
       from chairs
      ) union all
      (select Id, Name, NULL as CansSwing, NULL as CanDetachable,
              CotType, Storage, StorageType, FurnitureId 
       from cots
      )
     ) cc join
     furniture f
     on cc.furnitureid = f.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical learning problem, that's why I'm not giving you the code to solve this but all the insights you need to do so.

You have multiple approaches possible, but I'm describing two simple ones:

1) Use the UNION statement to join two separate queries one for Chair and the other for Cot, bare in mind that both SELECT have to return the same structure.

```
SELECT 
    a1,
    a2,
    etc..
FROM table1 a1
JOIN table2 a2 ON a1.some = a2.some
UNION
SELECT 
    a1,
    a3,
    etc..
FROM table1 a1
JOIN table3 a3 ON a1.some = a3.some
```

2) You can do it all in one SELECT statement using a LEFT JOIN to both tables and and in the select using COALESCE or ISNULL to get the values for one table or the other. In the WHERE condition you have to force one or the other join to be not null.

```
SELECT
    a1,
    COALESCE(a2,a3) as col2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 a2 ON a1.some = a2.some
LEFT JOIN table3 a3 ON a1.some = a3.some
WHERE 
    a2.some IS NOT NULL
    OR a3.some IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, i tried and learnt how to handle the above example. I am learner and came across with this super and sub types problem and designed the DB according to my learning and now facing the issue of getting the list of all types. Is there any easy way to retrieve the data? Also i do have more sub types say 10 then how can we handle this? Like two different queries and after that we can combine the results OR views OR any other better solution. I have to retrieve the data and fill it to the same classes as i have my model derived as same as my table structure.

Answer (score -1):

Mapping objects into relational models takes a degree of understanding of what is possible vs. what is wise in an RDBMS.  Object oriented database systems tried to go after problems like this (generally without much success) precisely because the problem statement is arguably not the right one.

Please consider just putting all of these in one table.  Then use null for the fields that don't really matter for each sub-type.  You will likely end up being a lot happier in the end since you can spend less time at runtime doing joins and instead just query the information you need and use indexing on the same table to find the fasted path for each query you want to run.

SELECT * FROM CombinedTable;

Comment: While this is good information, this question either falls into one of two camps - 1.) Some type of course work. 2.) Simplified example for a workplace query. They probably aren't in a position to be making design decisions in either case.

Comment: This is a well known problem in DB Design called Super and sub types and after going through several articles we designed the DB as shown in the example. Now we cant change the design but need to write a service which will give list of furnitures to display in UI.